# how to remove empty space from bars for a specific group, that was plotted as seaborn bar plot on data in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd, seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np

data = {"country":  ["USA", "USA",  "USA",  "GBR",  "GBR",  "GBR",  "IND",  "IND",  "IND"],
"sector":   ["Others", "Sec1", "Sec2",  "Others",   "Sec2", "Sec1", "Others",   "Sec1", "Sec3"],
"counts":   [8763,  8121,   7822,   580,    481,    460,    332,    193,    154]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['counts_log'] = df['counts'].apply(lambda x: np.log10(x))
```

When I am plotting this data using the following code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(18, 6))
sns.barplot(x='country', y='counts_log', hue='sector', data=df, palette='tab10')
plt.legend([],[], frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

I get the following issue (there is always some space between the bars of IND):

[image: Bar plot of the data]

Whatever I had tried, it is not going away. How to fix the issue?

Comment: Have you tried messing around with the `figsize`?

Comment: Before we proceed any further, is your Sec2 data really missing for IND or is that a typo? In your dictionary you have Sec3 for IND and Sec2 for the other countries.

Comment: @ObjectJosh - no, I was a lot careful with that... :)

Comment: @pakpe - no typo, the dataset is like that... thanks.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you've got missing values in your DataFrame.

You can clearly see them pivoting the df

```
pivot = df.pivot(index=['country'], columns=['sector'], values='counts_log')
print(pivot)
```

that gives

```
sector     Others      Sec1      Sec2      Sec3
country                                        
GBR      2.763428  2.662758  2.682145       NaN
IND      2.521138  2.285557       NaN  2.187521
USA      3.942653  3.909610  3.893318       NaN
```

So, there is "space" in `IND` `Sec2` because you have no data. Same for `GBR` `Sec3` and `USA` `Sec3`.

The only workaround I can suggest is to plot in subplots like

```
color_map = {
    'Others': 'C0',
    'Sec1': 'C1',
    'Sec2': 'C2',
    'Sec3': 'C3',
}
df['color'] = df.sector.map(color_map)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5), sharey=True)
for i, country in enumerate(df.country.unique()):
    _df = df[df.country==country].sort_values(by='sector')
    sns.barplot(
        ax=ax[i],
        data=_df,
        x='sector', y='counts_log',
        palette=_df.color
    )
    ax[i].set(
        title=country
    )
```

[image]

Maybe this is not exactly what you were searching for but hope it can help.