# Skip bars in Seaborn bar plot for which no data exists

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm creating a bar plot using Seaborn for a Pandas dataframe containing multiple features. For some of these feature combinations no data exists, which causes a gap in my bar plot.

This can be seen in the following plot, e.g. for `Prime Type = PO` and `Overlap = aux` no data exists, resulting in a gap:

[image: Bar Plot]

```
sns.catplot(
    data=lexboost_df, 
    x="Prime Type",
    y="Priming Effect",
    hue="Overlap",
    kind="bar",
    hue_order=['core', 'det', 'prep',  'aux', 'allfunc'],
)
```

I was wondering if it is possible using seaborn to not have these gaps in my bars, grouping all existing bars for each condition on the `x` axis together.

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66862337/how-to-remove-empty-space-from-bars-for-a-specific-group-that-was-plotted-as-se

Comment: Another visualization is that data is skipped.

Comment: @mcsoini that's certainly very related to my issue, thanks for linking it! Looks like there's no direct fix for this in seaborn, I'll have to work around it in some way.